# Generate Combinations in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine

I have an input row which contains the cells:

- 30
- 30
- 30
- 50
- 50
- 60
- 100

I want to generate all possible [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of length 3 from this set. So I would want rows containing 3 populated cells and the elements of each row would contain a unique set independent of order. In other words I would not have a 50, 30, 50 and a 30, 50, 50.

I've done this by hand so this may not be perfect but I believe my output should be:

- 30, 30, 30
- 30, 30, 50
- 30, 30, 60
- 30, 30, 100
- 30, 50, 50
- 30, 50, 60
- 30, 50, 100
- 30, 60, 100
- 50, 50, 60
- 50, 50, 100
- 50, 60, 100

I know that I can generate these with VBA, but I'd like to know: Does Excel have any native commands for generating these rows?

Comment: Why not 30 30 100?

Comment: @Raystafarian Stink, and 30, 30, 60, I have edited.

Comment: Isn't 30 30 60 the same as 30 60 30?

Comment: @Raystafarian Right again, that should have read 30, 60, 60

Comment: @Raystafarian wah! There is only 1x60. Whatever, I think it's right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `CROSSJOIN` function in Excel (PowerPivot add-in required for Excel 2010 & 2013 which you can download for free [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7609)).  Details about the `CROSSJOIN` function can be found on the [MSDN website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492168?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

In sum, set up your base data as two (duplicate) tables `table1` & `table2` making sure they have different column names, then use `CROSSJOIN(table1, table2)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't seen this link already, it could be of use. There are some formula examples down the bottom. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692653/excel-vba-to-create-every-possible-combination-of-a-range

However, the `CROSSJOIN` answer above is a much cleaner way.